# Select total of rows, total of field1 = 1, total of field1 = 0 in a single query?

Tags: mysql, count, subtotal

I have the following table :

```
id  | command_id    | started_at            | ended_at              | rows_involved | completed
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 1             | 2015-05-20 12:02:25   | 2015-05-20 12:02:28   | 1             | 1
2   | 1             | 2015-05-20 12:02:47   | NULL                  | NULL          | 0
3   | 1             | 2015-05-20 12:11:10   | NULL                  | NULL          | 0
4   | 1             | 2015-05-20 12:11:46   | NULL                  | NULL          | 0
5   | 1             | 2015-05-20 12:12:25   | NULL                  | NULL          | 0
```

I want to fetch a COUNT of rows where `started_at is '2015-05-20' AND commande_id = 1` and I want to get 2 sub totals, 1 is the total of these rows where `completed = 1` and 1 is the total of these rows where `completed = 0`.

Expected data set is then the following :

```
array(4) {
    ["totalRows"]=> 5
    ["name"]=> "evo:send_post_registration_mail_1"
    ["totalCompleted"] => 1
    ["totalUncompleted"] => 4
}
```

The "name" column is not important, is a join with another table on command_id field.

My current query is the following, but it doesn't fetch the 2 subtotals :

```
SELECT COUNT(s0_.id) AS totalRows, s1_.name AS name 
FROM sf_command_executions s0_ 
INNER JOIN sf_commands s1_ ON (s1_.id = s0_.command_id) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s0_.started_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-05-20' 
GROUP BY s0_.command_id
```

Can I fetch these 2 subtotals within that single query ?

Comment: The function around `s0_.started_at` in the predicate (WHERE clause) prevents MySQL from making effective use of an index. Assuming `started` column is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, this could be rewritten to reference the *bare* column, and allow for an index range scan operation. **`WHERE s0_.started_at >= '2015-05-20' AND s0_.started_at < '2015-05-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. Use an expression like this in your SELECT list...

```
SELECT ...
     , SUM(IF(s0_.completed=1,1,0)) AS tot_completed_1
     , SUM(IF(s0_.completed=0,1,0)) AS tot_completed_0
```

You can achieve the same thing using a (more ANSI-standards compliant) `CASE` expression:

```
     , SUM(CASE WHEN s0_.completed = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS tot_completed_1
```

Or you can use even shorter MySQL shorthand, since boolean expressions return a value of 1, 0 or NULL:

```
     , SUM(s0_.completed=1) AS tot_completed_1
```

---

**EDIT**

The following doesn't address the question you asked (see above for an answer to the question you asked). But I wanted to point out the predicate on the `started_at` column (i.e. the `WHERE` clause).

```
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s0_.started_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-05-20'
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `DATE_FORMAT` function wrapped around the column reference prevents MySQL from using an index range scan operation to satisfy that predicate.

That is, MySQL has to evaluate that function on *every* row in the table, and then compare the result from the expression to a literal value.

If `started_at` is defined as a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, we can rewrite that to an equivalent condition, but on the *bare* `started_at` column. That would allow MySQL to use an index range scan operation. For example, we could get the same rows writing it like this:

```
 WHERE s0_.started_at >= '2015-05-20'
   AND s0_.started_at <  '2015-05-20' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

If `started_at` is defined as a `DATE`, we could reference the bare column with an equality comparison. There's no need for a `DATE_FORMAT` function.

If we have to use a function to do some sort of conversion so the values can be compared, we'd prefer a function to wrapped around the literal rather than the column reference. Around the literal, that function only has to be evaluated once.

This isn't actually required in this case, but just as an example of wrapping the literal in a function:

```
 WHERE s0_.started_at >= STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-20','%Y-%m-%d')
   AND s0_.started_at <  STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-20','%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Note (again) that using the `STR_TO_DATE` function isn't actually required; this is just demonstrating a pattern. If we did need to do a conversion, we'd prefer that to be on the literal side, rather than on the column, to allow MySQL to make use of an available index on `started_at`.

Comment: accepting both answers, the ANSI-standards compliant is the only-one working in my case, because i'm using Doctrine DQL to build the query. the shorthand you proposed returned a Doctrine error. Thank a lot !

Comment: I just read your edit note about DATE_FORMAT. I totally understand how to get rid of it, but I dont understand why it would be better to avoid using it. It would make the sql statement be faster ?

Comment: @VaN: It would be great if we had a guarantee that would make a SQL statement more efficient, but we don't get such a guarantee. However, it many cases, it can and does make the statement more efficient, when a suitable index is available. Wrapping the column in a function **disables** MySQL from being able to effectively use an index range scan operation. The **function** has to be evaluated for *every* row in the table (that isn't filtered out by another predicate.) With a predicate on a **bare** column, MySQL can perform a range scan operation on a suitable index, which can be much faster.

Comment: Ok, I edited my query accordingly. I couldn't use INTERVAL because doctrine doesn't support it. So I made the operation directly in the value : `->where('ce.startedAt >= :start')
            ->setParameter('start', $datetime->format('Y-m-d'))
            ->andWhere('ce.startedAt < :end')
            ->setParameter('end', $datetime->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d'))`

Comment: @Van: Yep. That looks like the pattern we prefer to see. (I don't know much about Doctrine, but it does generate SQL statements that run against the database, and I do know about SQL.) A likely candidate for most suitable index would be **`... ON sf_command_executions (command_id, started_at, id)`**. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional sum as

```
SELECT 
COUNT(s0_.id) AS totalRows, 
s1_.name AS name ,
sum(s0_.completed=1) as totalCompleted,
sum(s0_.completed=0) as totalUncompleted
FROM sf_command_executions s0_ 
INNER JOIN sf_commands s1_ ON (s1_.id = s0_.command_id) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s0_.started_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-05-20' 
GROUP BY s0_.command_id
```

Comment: accepting both answers, the ANSI-standards compliant is the only-one working in my case, because i'm using Doctrine DQL to build the query. the shorthand you proposed returned a Doctrine error, but the idea is here.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT COUNT(s0_.id) AS totalRows, s1_.name AS name, 
(select count(S2_.id) from sf_command_executions S2_ where s0_.command_id=S2_.command_id and s2_.completed = 1) AS totalCompleted,
(select count(S2_.id) from sf_command_executions S2_ where s0_.command_id=S2_.command_id and s2_.completed = 0) AS totalUncompleted
FROM sf_command_executions s0_ 
INNER JOIN sf_commands s1_ ON (s1_.id = s0_.command_id) 
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(s0_.started_at,'%Y-%m-%d') = '2015-05-20' 
GROUP BY s0_.command_id
```

Comment: the 2 answers above dont use subqueries as yours, they are probably way more optimized.